# TinyMCE - toggle dark-theme after init

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

after the `tinymce.init()` i can toggle the readOnly setting like this:

```
editor.mode.set("design");
editor.mode.set("readonly");
```

but how can i toggle the dark theme for the editor and the content?

this will not work:

```
  editor.mode.set.content_css("dark");
  editor.mode.set.skin("dark-oxide");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible. All the settings defined in the `tinymce.init()` function cannot be changed without reinitialization. However, reinitialization can be done very fast. You will need to perform 4 steps:

1. Save current content somewhere with [`getContent()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#getcontent)
2. Destroy the TinyMCE instance with [`destroy()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#destroy)
3. Reinitialize
4. Use [`setContent()`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent) to add the content saved on step 1.